warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration
i'm getting this warnings react native project ,
my project in VS code and i related to Xcode
my macOS is M1.
i try adding [CP-User][Hermes], but i have same warning.
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')

Uncheck Based on dependency analysis on the Build Phase.

Having this same issue in RN 73.2 since upgrading to ios 17.2

I had the same issue and hadn't changed anything in my project but I updated to MacOS Sonoma 14.4 and it forced me to update ios to 17.2 in my simulator after it deleted all my old simulators.
I found a solution that worked for me here
Open your ios/.xcode.env and change it to the node version you are using. I'm using nvm with 18.17.1 so I did:
export NODE_BINARY=~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node

